# Why the C++ code couldn't display bitmap?(code from textbook)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to accompelish a example in textbook.Although I'm sure l type right code,but there's only a window with black background,no bitmap "C.bmp" having been loading.

Cause I don't master the C++ and winAPI,I just try to make the total code correct and no warning.And I surfer the Internet to find a meaningful answer but there's no code like me.I'm puzzled.

I have tried the absolute path,but it still doesn't work.
image returns (HBITMAP)0x0 and GetLastError returns zero.
const char* filename，but the program still happens
MinGW,gcc 4.9.2 compiler

```
void DrawBitmap(const char *filename,int x,int y)
{
    //load the bitmap image
    HBITMAP image = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(0,filename,IMAGE_BITMAP,
    0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    GetLastError();
    //read the bitmap's properties
    BITMAP bm;
    GetObject(image,sizeof(BITMAP),&bm);
    //create a device context for the bitmap
    HDC hdcImage = CreateCompatibleDC(device);
    SelectObject(hdcImage,image);
    //draw the bitmap to the window (bit block transfer)
    BitBlt(
        device,                 //destination device context    
        x,y,                    //x,y location on destination
        bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight, //width,height of source bitmap
        hdcImage,               //source bitmap device context
        0,0,                    //start x,y on source bitmap
        SRCCOPY);               //blit method
    //delete the device context and bitmap
    DeleteDC(hdcImage);
    DeleteObject((HBITMAP)image);
}
void Game_Run()
{
    if(gameover == true) return;
    //get the drawing surface
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(window,&rect);
    //draw bitmap at random location
    int x = rand() % (rect.right -rect.left);
    int y = rand() % (rect.bottom -rect.top);
    const char* filename = "E:\\Study\\time\\Code\\C++\\gameloop\\bmp.bmp";
    DrawBitmap(filename,x,y);
}
```

I just want to load bitmap and know why it is.

Comment: Your code seems to works fine whatever it is supposed to do. I bet your absolute path looks like this: `"C:\SomePath\SomeFile.bmp"` when it should look like this: `"C:\\SomePath\\SomeFile.bmp"`. Backslashes need to be escaped in C. BTW you don't check if [`LoadImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea) succeeds. It returns `NULL` is it was not successful. Read the documentation.

Comment: if `LoadImage` returns `NULL`, the file could not be loaded for some reason, in that case call [`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) to find out why `LoadImage` has failed.

Comment: Please update the code in the question. I mean the new code that tests if `LoadImage` was successful.

Comment: Change another bmp picture and try again.

Comment: [edit] your question and show your new code with `GetLastError`.

Comment: I know why it is! It's l change the .jpg file with a .bmp suffix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running your code, put aside the code logic first, just to show the BMP image, you did not add the correct image path.

You can try to add the absolute path of the picture.

Like this:

```
DrawBitmap("C:\\Users\\strives\\source\\C.bmp",x,y); //This is my picture path. Please enter your picture path correctly.
```

**Updated:**

I retested the code with MinGW, GCC 4.9.2 compiler. It can display the image correctly. Look at my attached GIF picture.

[image: 1]

From the results of your feedback later, `Loadimage` return NULL, you use `GetLasterror` to test the return value of 0. In theory, if the image failed to load, it will return 2. Maybe you can use `int error = GetLasterror()` to retest the return value. At the same time, you need to make sure that the BMP image you added is correct, opened, and in BMP format. picture

Comment: Thank you a lot! l'm very appreciative to your kindness for my stupid question.l have tried the method but it still only has a window with black background.I speak English terribly!

Comment: @Cewbie Please see the update of my answer.

Comment: I know why it is! It's l change the .jpg file with a .bmp suffix.

Comment: @Cewbie You can't change the suffix directly. You need to use special image conversion tools to convert the image format.

Comment: Yeah, .jpg still be opened as a jpg with .bmp suffix.Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the bitmap is not being displayed is most likely because you have the bitmap file in the wrong place. Build this code in Release, look in the project directory, find the actual release executable, copy "C.bmp" into the directory where the executable is and run the executable by double-clicking on it. You will see that it works.

You do not say which IDE you are using, but, assuming some flavor of Visual Studio, to get this working by launching from the IDE, unless you have changed settings, by default the "Working Directory" Visual Studio uses for debugging is the project directory. If you look at where your code is in the file system, find where the solution file is -- the .sln file. You should see a directory that is a sibling of the solution file that is named whatever you named your project. Put "C.bmp" in there, at the top-level, and try launching from Visual Studio.

Beyond this issue this code has a lot of problems, by the way. To get you started, it is a bad idea to reload the bitmap from the file system every time you want to paint it.

Comment: Thanks!Now I have used the absolute path but it's still not working.The IDE is Dev C++.

Comment: if you put a breakpoint after the call to LoadImage does image contain a non-zero HBITMAP?

Comment: the value of image is (HBITMAP)0x0

Comment: image is zero,GetLastError() is zero too.

Comment: That means it didn’t load

Comment: I know why it is! It's l change the .jpg file with a .bmp suffix.

Answer (score -1):

Calling `LoadImage` is not enough. It is painted black, because EVERY color is black. ALso, you need to repaint the window. You should load palette, content of which which may depend on your context.
Example from https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/158898/howto-how-to-use-loadimage-to-read-a-bmp-file

```
BOOL LoadBitmapFromBMPFile( LPTSTR szFileName, HBITMAP *phBitmap,
   HPALETTE *phPalette )
   {

   BITMAP  bm;

   *phBitmap = NULL;
   *phPalette = NULL;

   // Use LoadImage() to get the image loaded into a DIBSection
   *phBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage( NULL, szFileName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
               LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE );
   if( *phBitmap == NULL )
     return FALSE;

   // Get the color depth of the DIBSection
   GetObject(*phBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm );
   // If the DIBSection is 256 color or less, it has a color table
   if( ( bm.bmBitsPixel * bm.bmPlanes ) <= 8 )
   {
   HDC           hMemDC;
   HBITMAP       hOldBitmap;
   RGBQUAD       rgb[256];
   LPLOGPALETTE  pLogPal;
   WORD          i;

   // Create a memory DC and select the DIBSection into it
   hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC( NULL );
   hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( hMemDC, *phBitmap );
   // Get the DIBSection's color table
   GetDIBColorTable( hMemDC, 0, 256, rgb );
   // Create a palette from the color tabl
   pLogPal = (LOGPALETTE *)malloc( sizeof(LOGPALETTE) + (256*sizeof(PALETTEENTRY)) );
   pLogPal->palVersion = 0x300;
   pLogPal->palNumEntries = 256;
   for(i=0;i<256;i++)
   {
     pLogPal->palPalEntry[i].peRed = rgb[i].rgbRed;
     pLogPal->palPalEntry[i].peGreen = rgb[i].rgbGreen;
     pLogPal->palPalEntry[i].peBlue = rgb[i].rgbBlue;
     pLogPal->palPalEntry[i].peFlags = 0;
   }
   *phPalette = CreatePalette( pLogPal );
   // Clean up
   free( pLogPal );
   SelectObject( hMemDC, hOldBitmap );
   DeleteDC( hMemDC );
   }
   else   // It has no color table, so use a halftone palette
   {
   HDC    hRefDC;

   hRefDC = GetDC( NULL );
   *phPalette = CreateHalftonePalette( hRefDC );
   ReleaseDC( NULL, hRefDC );
   }
   return TRUE;

   }
```

Next, you have to piant it to window:

```
case WM_PAINT:
   {
     PAINTSTRUCT   ps;
     HBITMAP       hBitmap, hOldBitmap;
     HPALETTE      hPalette, hOldPalette;
     HDC           hDC, hMemDC;
     BITMAP        bm;

   hDC = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );

   if( LoadBitmapFromBMPFile( szFileName, &hBitmap, &hPalette ) )
   {
      GetObject( hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm );
      hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC( hDC );
      hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( hMemDC, hBitmap );
      hOldPalette = SelectPalette( hDC, hPalette, FALSE );
      RealizePalette( hDC );

      BitBlt( hDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight,
              hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );

      SelectObject( hMemDC, hOldBitmap );
      DeleteObject( hBitmap );
      SelectPalette( hDC, hOldPalette, FALSE );
      DeleteObject( hPalette );
   }
   EndPaint( hWnd, &amp;ps );

   }
   break;
```

The example there is clumsy, because it loads image every time window is painted. You must want to reorganize code so image will be loaded only once. But it's what you should do - to paint it within window event handler, because every time windows is moved, resized or otherwise invalidated (obscured), it requires repainting.

Comment: The code from Microsoft page is very old, from the days of 8-bit (or less) graphics card. New 32-bit graphics cards don't need to worry about palettes.