# (Bitmap)LoadImage() returns NULL and GetLastError() returns 0

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to draw a bitmap file on window. So I used (HBITMAP)LoadImage() and it returns NULL.
I used GetLastError to see the problem but it returns 0 too.
I'm working on goorm ide(windows application).

```
    HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW( NULL, L"C:\\Users\\Asd\\Downloads\\image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE );

    if(hBitmap == NULL){
        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
        if(errorCode != 0){
            LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
            FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
                NULL,
                errorCode,
                0,
                (LPTSTR)&messageBuffer,
                0,
                NULL);
                MessageBox(NULL, messageBuffer, "hBitmap is NULL!" , MB_OK);
                }else{
                    MessageBox(NULL, "hBitmap is null but errorCode is 0", "???" , MB_OK);
                }
            }
```

If I change the "image.bmp" to "asdf.bmp" in the code, It says "there is no file." so I'm sure that It found file but seems not working right. when I print Width and Height of bitmap, It shows strange number(like 12312321, -3453453). I can't find what is problem.

I tried this too:
(from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/158898/howto-how-to-use-loadimage-to-read-a-bmp-file)

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage( NULL, "image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
               LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE );
```

Comment: From the documentation for the LoadImageA function: "If the fuLoad parameter includes the LR_LOADFROMFILE value, lpszName is the name of the file that contains the stand-alone resource (icon, cursor, or bitmap file). Therefore, set hinst to NULL.". So basically you should set the first parameter to NULL and not try to get your module.

Comment: I tried hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage( NULL, "image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE );
But still same errorMessage.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your problem is that hBitmap is not declared as a pointer. Declare it: HBITMAP* hBitmap.

Comment: I tried 
`HBITMAP* hBitmap = NULL;
hBitmap = (HBITMAP*)LoadImage( NULL, "image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
               LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE ); `same. @o_weisman

Comment: I suggest you try reading into a HANDLE variable without the cast to see if the function actually returns NULL or if it's the cast that's causing that.

Comment: `HANDLE handle = LoadImageA( NULL, "image.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE );
char buf[256];
wsprintf(buf, "value: %d", handle);
MessageBox(hWnd, buf, "HANDLE" , MB_OK);`

I tried this and messageBox shows me value: 0. So I think cast doesn't cause that. @o_weisman

Comment: @o_weisman `HBITMAP` is already a pointer type, using `HBITMAP*` is wrong. And a typecast can't produce a NULL unless the value being casted is already NULL to begin with.

Comment: @이재원 just an FYI, `%d` is the wrong format specifier to use for printing a handle, `%p` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @이재원 have you tried using an absolute path to the `.bmp` file? You are currently using a relative path. Also see [LoadImage() returns NULL and GetLastError() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242193/). One thing I notice is that your `WM_PAINT` code isn't doing any error handling, and it destroys `hBitmap` after the 1st paint, leaving `hBitmap` invalid for subsequent paints. Since you load `hBitmap` in `WM_CREATE`, you should be destroying it in `WM_DESTROY` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Absolute path still returns NULL. and I'm sure it found the file because of the same reason in above.
I change the code in link so it doesn't destroy hBitmap in WM_PAINT.

Comment: @이재원 then short of some other memory error, the logical culprit is likely a problem with the `.bmp` file itself. Have your tried using other `.bmp` files?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just tried other bmp file converted by web converter(jpeg to bmp). And it's same error. and I inquired goorm ide with a link of this question. I will update when I get the answer. Thanks for answering my question and trying to help me.

Comment: @이재원 Can you display it correctly after you get the correct bmp image?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT No. I can't. And my original bmp file is correct too.Because it is converted by web converter.

Comment: @이재원 Can you provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I need to reproduce your issue, and help solve it.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT I updated a better example. And the bmp file(image.bmp) is in full code link(in resource or bin folder, just double click it to download.). Let me know the result after you reproduce it.

Comment: @이재원   I can't get valid information from the link you provided. This is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWiPT.png). Even if I try to sign in, the result is the [same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUGAZ.png).

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LYiATychwJKwsYveICW067cp-_6py7-U) Try this link.

Comment: @이재원 Yes, there is a problem with your image format. Try it with my [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WBggrKEi2_gs25yNMNt052R7YWOcPPAE/view).

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT It says I need access permission. Maybe It's not public. What was the problem and How did you converted it?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT OMG It's working.

Comment: @이재원 Sorry ,I have corrected [it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tZEhISNhJQPyAFpqQ0noEZ8phTjVL48q/view) again ,please try again.

Comment: @이재원 I just used the online image conversion tool, maybe you can try another one.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Link plz. I want to make it sure.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Thanks for your help and kindness. Now I feel alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create the simplest Windows Desktop Application.

And only added `WM_CREATE` and `WM_PAINT` message events.

I added my own bmp image and can successfully load the image.

Like this:

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), L"C:\\Users\\strives\\Desktop\\panda.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
            LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

From your answer in the comments, you have tried to use an absolute path to load the image, but you have not considered a problem. That's the image format, if you just changed the suffix of a JPG image to .bmp, then your `hBitmap` will return 0, and `GetLasterror` will also return 0.

So all you have to do is use a properly formatted BMP image. If there is no such image, please use the image conversion format tool to convert.

In addition, I have encountered a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57690101/11128312) before, you can refer.

Comment: `LoadImage()` is documented to return an error code via `GetLastError()` on failure. The fact that it can report 0 is a bug, IMHO. I would have expected something like `ERROR_INVALID_DATA` or similar if the file were not in a valid BMP format.

Answer (score 3):

Got this with BOOL LoadBitmap(UINT nIDResource) and a GIMP-created bmp. Load the resource bmp file into Paint and do some pseudo-change to convince Paint that you changed the bmp. Save the bmp. The problem has gone away! I did not drill deeper to find the root cause. LoadBitmap does not like GIMP-created bmp files.

Comment: Same experience except image was created in linux with "mogrify -format bmp *.jpg". Bottom line is loadimage is very picky about its image sources.

Comment: Even weirder: Running the executable in wine, with the GIMP image worked fine, but failed on my Windows machine. Re-saving the file in Paint fixed the issue,

Comment: Same here, I got it fixed by ticking "Compatibility Options -> Do not write color space information" on the image export dialog.