# LoadImage not loading the bmp file?

Tags: c++, winapi

I load the bmp file as such;

```
        HBITMAP filebmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,_T("C:\\bmp.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    
    DWORD errorMessageID = GetLastError();
    
                                        if (errorMessageID == 0)
                                        {
                                            break;
                                        }

HBITMAP CreateCompatibleBitmap(filebmp);
```

but when debugging,

> filebmp is NULL 0x000000000

Is this the wrong BMP file? In my code, I save it as a BMP file.

What am I dong wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: GETLASTERROR() RETURNS 0.

Comment: Per `LoadImage`'s documentation: "*If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).*"  So, what does `GetLastError()` say is the reason why `LoadImage()` is failing?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, getlasterror() returns 0

Comment: Please show a [mcve], including the code that queries the calling thread's last error code and the code the displays this value.

Comment: @IInspectable, just updated.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I know this, that is how my code is.

Comment: @Bob see [(Bitmap)LoadImage() returns NULL and GetLastError() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152337/)

Comment: *"What am I dong wrong?"* - You're likely using an authoring tool, that doesn't produce valid BMP files. The easy way out: Open the file in MS Paint, and just save it again. MS Paint is *extremely* lenient in accepting input, and strict in producing output. That should solve your immediate issue.

Comment: If `LoadImage` returns NULL and `GetLastError` returns 0, it means that the image you are using is not valid.You may directly modify the suffix or convert the generated bmp format through an online tool, try to use an image conversion tool to convert the image.